# Averaging value based off previous value Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
value 1         value 2
1               10
4               1
5               8
6               10
10              12
```

I want to go down each entry of `value 1`, average the previous value, and then create a new column beside `value 2` with the average.

The output needs to look like:

```
value 1         value 2        avg
1               10             nan
4               1              2.5
5               8              4.5 
6               10             5.5
10              12             8.0
.
.
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: It all depends on how the data is represented. Do you have a list? A list of lists? Try to explain it in the question and add an example of what you tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)

You can sum a series with the shifted version of itself:

```
df['avg'] = (df['value1'] + df['value1'].shift()) / 2

print(df)

   value1  value2  avg
0       1      10  NaN
1       4       1  2.5
2       5       8  4.5
3       6      10  5.5
4      10      12  8.0
```